# Update React front end when DynamoDb item attribute is updated

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-streams

I am building a react app with a node.js serverless backend through AWS that needs to sync real time results from my Dynamo DB table.

My app lists the items and if the items attribute "status" === "new" it will show the list item. If the "status" has been updated to "scheduled" it hides the list item. I need to push these updates to the front end as soon as it happens so I dont get duplicate "scheduled" updates from multiple users.

How should I go about this? Can I use Dynamo Db Streams?

Any insight is much appreciated. If you need to look at some of my code let me know I will update my question with it!

Answer (score 1):

You could use AWS Amplify to quickly hookup your react with dynamodb via AWS appsync. You can get real time updates using graphql. https://aws.amazon.com/amplify/features/#API

Comment: Im currently using AWS Amplify in my project. Im not 100% sure on how to use graphql.